# Does Setup Audit Log capture all changes to a Community setup?

Tags: administration, setup-audit-log

I'm trying to track down what I believe was a mistake in a community configuration; specifically, to the choice of Login Page (Setup->Customize->Community->All Communities->Manage->Administration->Login & Registration).  I cannot find any mention in the Setup Audit Log.  I've gone back as far as a known release date on which the Login Page setting was changed, but I can't find that change in the Audit Log either.  These changes occur inside the special community setup screen, are they supposed to captured?  Are they logged elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Came across this post while doing some research and finding out there is currently no tracking for changes made to Communities Settings > Sharing set

Here's an article which describes what changes are tracked for communities :
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000322384&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1